# Write custom SQL query using JPA

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a JPA repository for a DB entity as follows:

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository
    extends  JpaRepository<Student, String>  {
}
```

`Student` entity is as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "custom-uuid")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "custom-uuid",
      strategy = "generator.CustomUUIDGenerator")
  private String id;

  @Column(name = "roll_number")
  private String rollNumber;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;

  @LastModifiedDate
  @Column(name = "last_modified_date")
  @JsonIgnore
  private Instant lastModifiedDate = Instant.now();
```

Now, I would like to write the following SQL query using JPA as follows:

```
SELECT id, roll_number from  student where id=<id> order by last_modified_date desc;
```

Being new to JPA/Hibernate, I don't have an idea how to achieve this using JPA/Hibernate.

Could anyone please help here ?

Answer (score 1):

You could write something like:

```
String hql = "SELECT s.id, s.rollNumber FROM Student s WHERE s.id = :id ORDER BY s.lastModifiedDate DESC";
query.setParameter("id", 10);
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
List results = query.list();
```

Refer: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jpa/jpa_jpql.htm

Answer (score 0):

Create a new method in Repository

```java
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, String> {

    /**
     * List all student by criterias.
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Query(value = "SELECT id, roll_number from student where id=?1 order by last_modified_date desc;", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Student> listStudent(String id);

}
```

Reference document: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query